# Mapas de Google en Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps

Descargo la informacion de la url en json y lleno variables

```
private static PostResponseAsyncTask task;
```

OnCreate

```
task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(this);
    task.execute(url_localizacion+Dispositivo);
```

Ejecuto el task en la url+metodoGET

```
  @Override
public void processFinish(String s) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            Longitud = (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitud"));
            Latitud = (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitud"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Aqui mi pregunta estoy obteniendo la Latitud y Longitud de los datos de la base de datos en la nube pero me esta ejecutando el mapa de google antes.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng locMovil = new LatLng(parseDouble(Latitud),parseDouble(Longitud));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(locMovil).title(Dispositivo)); //Titulo de Marker
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(locMovil));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locMovil, (float) 16.0));
}
```

¿como puedo hacer que primero descargue la informacion de la nube y luego agregue las cordenadas de las variables `Longitud y Latitud` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes realizar es obtener las coordenadas en tu método y después llamar al método `onMapReady` con la siguiente instrucción:

```
tuSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Quedaría algo así:

```
@Override
public void processFinish(String s) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            Longitud = (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitud"));
            Latitud = (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitud"));
        }
        tuSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: eso solo haría que la pantalla se pusiera en negro hasta que se descarguen las coordenadas, si tardara unos segundos extras la app se cerrará

Comment: no entiendo porque ya no me quiere ejecutar el processFinish.

Comment: @ManuelMorales ¿Antes te entraba en el método? ¿Qué es lo que has cambiado? ¿Te aparece algún error?

Comment: de echo no me lo ejecuta en este activity de mapas, en los otros como si nada lo tengo así mira:
`public class Localizacion_HassMovil extends AppCompatActivity  implements OnMapReadyCallback,AsyncResponse {`

Comment: @ManuelMorales ¿Antes te ejecutaba este Activity? ¿O tampoco? Yo en mi caso utilizo un Fragment pero no recupero las coordenadas de la nube si no que las obtengo directamente del mapa (solo necesito las actuales). ¿Tienes más Activities de mapas? ¿Hay algo que cambie entre ellas?

Comment: hola me esta mandando al catch ya vi que si lo ejecuta:
`getMessage` manda esto: _End of input at character 0 of_

Comment: @ManuelMorales Mira a ver si la respuesta que estas obteniendo devuelve datos. Tiene toda la pinta de que te vuelve nula.

Comment: lo coloco en el navegador y funciona perfecto me devuelve datos.

Comment: @ManuelMorales ¿Y en la aplicación? Pon algún Log.d para poder ver los datos que te devuelve en la consola. Puede que la llamada esté mal.

Comment: nunca he utilizado el `Log.d` como deberia hacerlo?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50856/discussion-between-manuel-morales-and-error404).

Comment: hola el problema era al momento de ejecutar el metodo de obtencion de datos es decir:
`task.execute(url_localizacion+Dispositivo);` al momento de enviar la varible `Dispositivo`. Esta conenia espacios y no obtiene nada.